# How to change languages in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, database

Currently I am working on a WPF project... Initially those words are in English, but when user clicks on "Japanese", the whole project will be change to "Japanese", if click on "French", it will be change to "French" etc...

I have tried using 'xml' to store all my texts and used "Storyboard" but it doesn't work...

So do anyone knows how can I archieve it... Is good if there are some working samples/examples to shown...

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

WPF localization basics http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788718.aspx

Solutions and samples http://weblogs.asp.net/fmarguerie/archive/2009/05/12/localization-in-wpf.aspx

Comment: I need to store texts in database, and retrieve it from the database. So I doubt is using this method.. Do you have any idea beside using this localization way? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is internationalization.

Refer [here](http://www.klopfenstein.net/lorenz.aspx/internationalization-in-net-and-wpf-presentation-foundation) for an example.